# What are other ways to fake underwater environment?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

The most realistic way to create an underwater scene is using volume shader, but looking for a more faster way(i.e. to fake), are there any ways besides these. I tried to search up for it but it doesn't seem there are much tutorials on it. Could anyone suggest some ways?

Comment: You can make every thing in the post production,Starting from the absorption using the z depth pass,and the light distortion using the displace node,and the overall colors using the color balance node.

Comment: @Omar Ahmad, I didn't mean to composite after I render, just meant to make it inside of blender.

Comment: @bzal I think Omar meant inside of Blender's built-in compositor. The output you get after rendering would be passed through the compositor before being written to a file, so you wouldn't need to do any extra processing on it with other software. Also, a Z-depth pass will probably be faster (in performance) than setting up a Cycles material for it. Although if you really want to, you can probably set up volume shading that gets denser with distance using a Gradient Texture.